# Log into Windows 8 Account without the need to type the Username

Tags: windows-8.1, passwords, login-screen

I am using Windows 8.1 with a single user account (the admin account). When I boot up the computer, I am presented with the usual login screen, but rather than simply typing in my password, the screen says "Other User", and has both a username *and* password box.

I would like to keep the computer password protected, but don't want the hassle of having to type my username in each time I boot up, since I am the only user, and my account is the administrator account. Ideally, I would see the same behavior as happens when I am already logged in and lock the system (my username is displayed, and I only have to type in my password).

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons you should create a Standard User Account on your PC and use that as your default account.

I think you must type the Username to Sign in because you changed the Local Security Policy. So try this:

- Hit <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>
- Type Local Security Policy or secpol.msc
- Right Click and Run as Administrator.
- Navigate to Local Policies <kbd>→</kbd> Security Options <kbd>→</kbd> Interactive logon: Do not display last user name
- Disable it.
- Sign out and Sign in

[image: Sign In in Windows 8 with only using the password]

You can also do this via the registry

- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type regedit and run as Administrator
- Navigate to
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`
- set the dontdisplaylastusername to 0.

Check [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc957392.aspx) the Microsoft Documentation.

Comment: I used the first solution presented, and the problem is now solved.

Comment: @CaptainProg Nice to hear that it helped you. The second solution is for those who don't own the Professional version of Windows. But the first solution is better, cause messing with the registry is risky. If you can please +1